# Casper.js/Phantom.js not submitting data

Tags: forms, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using Casper.js to automate submitting a form. The form's onSubmit method returns false and runs some javascript (onclick callback) before sending the data, so I have to use `clickLabel`, instead of `fill`. The data is prepopulated, I just have to click the Submit button. When I use Casper to do `clickLabel('Submit')`, the data isn't submitted. What am I doing wrong?

Edit - here's the markup of the label:

```
<a class="green_btn white font_18 arrow_btn_pad rad_5" onclick="$.shactivity.eoiPremiumSubmit('expressval');return false;" href="javascript:void(0);">
<span class="fl cursor_p">Submit</span>
<span class="white_right_arrow mar_l_7 block fl mar_t_6 cursor_p"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to use `fill` or `fillSelectors` with the submit flag set? In my tests the submit handlers are run. Please show the form markup. If the submit button is an `input` element then you will have to `click` it.

Comment: won't 'fill' just submit the form instead of executing the onclick callback?

Comment: No, it won't run the `onclick` handler, but only the `onsubmit` handler of the form. The same way you would fill out the form and press enter. If you really want to click the label then you should **provide the necessary markup of the label**. `clickLabel` is pretty limited in the functionality, so there might be a problem there.

Comment: added label markup to question

Answer (score 0):

`clickLabel` invokes `click` in your case with the XPath selector of `//*[text()='Submit']`. `click` in turn will try dispatch `mousefown` and `click` events on the `span` with the Submit text. But the span won't have any such event handlers on it since this is what the parent link is for. The above XPath selector won't select the actual Link which is a parent of the span element.

You need to click the actual link to trigger the action:

```js
casper.click(".green_btn.white.font_18.arrow_btn_pad.rad_5");
```

*or* with an XPath expression to select the parent based on the text:

```js
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.click(x("//*[text()='Submit']/.."));
```