# Casper.js: selector not found, even though it shows up in html

Tags: javascript, forms, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to automate filling a form through Casper.js. The form shows up in a modal popup, and is already populated with the data, so I just have to click the submit label.

I have the following code:

```
this.echo(this.getHTML('#modalContent'))
if(!casper.exists('.green_btn white font_18 arrow_btn_pad rad_5')) {
    this.echo('not found')
} else {
    this.echo('found')
}
this.clickLabel('Submit')
```

The html for the `modalContent` div logged to the console contains:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.shactivity.eoiSubmit('expressval');return false;" class="green_btn white font_18 arrow_btn_pad rad_5">
```

where `expressval` is the id of the form.

Since the html contains the selector, the next line should print 'found', but it prints 'not found'. More importantly, `clickLabel('Submit')` doesn't return any errors, but the form is not being submitted either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you post a separate question? You could have edited the [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186595/casper-js-phantom-js-not-submitting-data) one to make yourself clearer. Since the previous question had no answers, you could have salvaged it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CasperJS accepts [CSS3 selector strings](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/selectors.html#index-1) and yours is not a correct one. You want to use something like this:

```
this.echo(this.getHTML('#modalContent'))
if(!casper.exists('.green_btn.white.font_18.arrow_btn_pad.rad_5')) { //changed
    this.echo('not found')
} else {
    this.echo('found')
}
this.clickLabel('Submit')
```